# Redirect users based on the user group or access level after login in Joomla 3

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

i want Redirect users based on the user group or access level after login in Joomla 3 . For example (sarah is a Customer: after login redirect to CustomerManagment page) and (ted is a admin : after login redirect him to siteManagment page). What extension should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The free or paid version of [Redirect on Login](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/redirect-on-login) will do this for you.

I haven't used it but it looks like [Redirect After Login](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/access-a-security/site-access/redirect-after-login/) (not free) does this too.

You can likely find other similar extensions in the [Joomla Extensions Directory](https://extensions.joomla.org).